# A question about char cannot be converted to java.lang.String

Tags: java

I am working on a practice question:

Given a string, return a string made of the first 2 chars (if present), however, include the first char only if it is 'o' and include the second only if it is 'z', so "ozymandias" yields "oz".

```
startOz("ozymandias") → "oz"
startOz("bzoo") → "z"
startOz("oxx") → "o"
```

Below is my solution, but I don't know why it shows "incompatible types: char cannot be converted to java.lang.String". I was wondering if anyone can help me with my code. Thank you so much!

```
public String startOz(String str) {
  if (str.length()==1 && str.charAt(0)=='o'){
    return 'o';
  }
  if (str.length()<1){
    return "";
  }
  if (str.length()>=2 && str.charAt(0) =='o' && str.charAt(1) !='z'){
    return 'o';
  }
  if (str.length()>=2 && str.charAt(0) !='o' && str.charAt(1) =='z'){
    return 'z';
  }
  if (str.length()>=2 && str.charAt(0) =='o' && str.charAt(1) =='z'){
    return "oz";
  } else {
    return "";
  }
}
```

Comment: Because `'o'` is a `char`. `"o"` would be a string.

Comment: `'o'` is a `char` - a primitive type. It cannot be converted directly to the string `"o"` (notice the double quotes) - you'd need to explicitly do `String.valueOf('o')`.

Comment: just change the type of quotes from '' to "" for all return excpression

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you type a string in single quotation marks, it tells the compiler to consider whatever follows as a single character. Double quotation marks indicate a string. The function cannot return a char when it is expecting a String.

```
public String startOz(String str) {
  if (str.length()==1 && str.charAt(0)=='o'){
    return "o";
  }
  if (str.length()<1){
    return "";
  }
  if (str.length()>=2 && str.charAt(0) =='o' && str.charAt(1) !='z'){
    return "o";
  }
  if (str.length()>=2 && str.charAt(0) !='o' && str.charAt(1) =='z'){
    return "z";
  }
  if (str.length()>=2 && str.charAt(0) =='o' && str.charAt(1) =='z'){
    return "oz";
  } else {
    return "";
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 1):

Rainmaker et al are correct: the problem is that your method should return a String (a Java object), not a char (a Java primitive).  One good solution to the compile error is to return "o" (double quotes).

But perhaps you might find this a simpler solution:

```
public static boolean isNullOrEmpty(String s) {
  return s == null || s.isEmpty();
}

public String startOz(String str) {
  if (isNullOrEmpty(str)) {
    return "";
  } else if (str.startsWith("oz")) {
    return "oz";
  } else if (str.charAt(0) == 'o') {
    return "o";
  } else if (str.length() > 1 && str.charAt(1) == 'z') {
    return "z";
  } else {
    return "";
  }
```

Comment: Wow...thank you so much! I did not know "startsWith" and the solution you provided is so clear and really helps me think differently.

Comment: This runs, but if str.length()==0,  startOz("") → ""  it will show StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 0

Comment: Correct.  Or you'll get an NPE if it's null.  I added an additional static method, equivalent to .Net [string.IsNullOrEmpty()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.isnullorempty?view=net-6.0).

Comment: You get `java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException` for input `startOz("x")`

Answer (score 0):

You cannot retreive a `char` instead of `Stirng`. Do use `String.valueOf(ch)` instead.

By the way, just be a simple man! You can do the same with much less code.

```java
public static String startOz(String str) {
    String res = "";

    if (str != null) {
        if (str.length() > 0 && str.charAt(0) == 'o')
            res += 'o';
        if (str.length() > 1 && str.charAt(1) == 'z')
            res += 'z';
    }

    return res;
}
```

---

**Answer to comment.**

1. `StringBuilder` is a correct way to build a `String`, because `String` is immutable in `Java`. In case you are a beginner, I removed it.
2. `<condition> ? <true> : <false>` is called a **ternary operand**. if is similar like `if(<condition>) <true> else <false>;`
3. And finally I used `trim()` to remove `\0` from the beginning and the end of the string. A also removed it.

You can see my updated result.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! I am new to programming, and I was wondering if you could explain a little more. What's StringBuilder? I also don't understand the part "'o' ? 'o' : '\0'". Why do we need trim() at the end? Thank you so much!

Comment: @user13966876 see my answers above